# Receive Post Parameters In Magento 2 Controller

Tags: magento2, php, api, rest-api

I am calling HTTP request for controller, I am getting get parameters, but I am not able to receive post parameters in Controller.

Basically I want to call Magento 2 APIs and send customized response to application, for that I have created a **`simple module`**, which will call API and customized response and send response to application,

But I am not able to fetch post parameters from request.

Here are some of my files which can give an idea about problem,

**etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/api/token" method="POST">
        <service class="Spaarg\Api\Api\apiInterface" method="token"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Spaargcommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Spaarg\Api\Controller\Token;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheTypeList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheState;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool
     */
    protected $_cacheFrontendPool;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->_cacheState = $cacheState;
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Flush cache storage
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //$this->resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();  
        //return $this->resultPage;

        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
        $storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
        $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
        $baseUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl();

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($post);
        exit;

    }
}
```

It will be great if someone can help.

Comment: Please check Ur form tag with method post `$postParam = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('<param>');`

Comment: @Anand, could you help on how did you implement your custom api endpoint and get post params using controller? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To get Post data in controller you need to use following in your execute function.

```
public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($post);
    exit;

}
```

Comment: If I want to use custom method for getting post parameters then how will it possible?

Comment: @salma can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get post data from controller,

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

Here your full code,

**Also You have to declare storemanager object inside __construct() function of your php file instead of use dirctly objectmanager.**

I have updated your code as below,

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheTypeList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheState;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool
     */
    protected $_cacheFrontendPool;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->_cacheState = $cacheState;
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Flush cache storage
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $currentStore = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $baseUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl();

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($post);
        exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to unset/remove post params i.e.`$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`

Comment: @rakesh can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2

Answer (score 2):

Since `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` is now deprecated, this is the right way to do it :

```
<?php

namespace Spaarg\Api\Controller\Token;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Index implements HttpPostActionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $allParams = $this->_request->getParams();
        $oneParam = $this->_request->getParam('the_param_name');


    }
}
```

Note : `implements HttpGetActionInterface` for GET controllers.

Answer (score 1):

This works very well for grabbing POST data in a controller:

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.3 We can use the below code to get the post value in the controller.

```
namespace Module\Custom\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $allPostValues = $this->getRequest->getParams();
            $onePostValue = $this->getRequest->getParam('post_param');

            $this->logger->info($onePostValue);
            $this->logger->info(print_r($allPostValues,true));
            
            return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```